# Micropython : esp32 I2C. SRF10 sensor not returning values

Tags: esp32, i2c, micropython

I am using a SRF10 sensor connected to a esp32-kit.While using it to acquire data the light only flashes at the beginning when given power.My code is the following:

```
from machine import I2C, Pin
import time

#Distance units

unit_cm = 0x51


i2c = I2C(freq=100000,scl=Pin(18), sda=Pin(19))
address = 0x70 # from the scan


#Sensor range
range_mm = 255
i2c.writeto_mem(address, range_mm, bytearray(2))

#Begin reading
i2c.writeto_mem(address,unit_cm, bytearray(0))

#Reading after measurement
data = i2c.readfrom_mem(address, 0,4)
print(data)
```

And the data printed is b'\x05\x80\x00\x00 . The first two values make sense, but the other two, which should be the data of the distances, are always zero. What could be the problem?

Comment: I haven't used this sensor but you don't have any time delay between `Begin reading` and `Reading after measurement`. After starting a measurement, do you need to wait for some time until the measurement is complete?

Comment: @nekomatic. The sensor to read waits a time of 65ms, but this waiting time is implemented in the range when mentioned.But even when we put the time sleep  in the code to wait, it still doesnt print values different than zero.